# Return username and password to login form grails spring security

Tags: grails, spring-security

When a user fails authentication, I want the username and password to be returned to the form. 
I'm using the spring security core plugin with Grails and Spring Security LDAP. I've searched around for a while and have come up with zip. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` javadoc:

> If you want to retain the username, cache it in a customized AuthenticationFailureHandler

As for password there is no point to cache it, because it cannot be put back to form password field for security reasons.

Comment: besides, that's not really something you see on most websites.

Comment: I actually am seeing it more and more and it's quite convenient to just erase that last character you accidentally typed

Answer (score 3):

For future reference, as the above answers are either too vague to be helpful to those of us who are just beginning to learn this framework for the first time (prompting such questions as: what's an `AuthenticationFailureHandler`?  How do I implement one?  How do I connect it to my existing infrastructure that was magically created by the `<security:http>` namespace handler?) or no longer work (the code to store the username in `SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME` was removed from `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` as of version 3.1.0), here's a little more detail on the first answer:

- An `AuthenticationFailureHandler` is used by the login process to decide what to do when authentication fails.
- The default login form setup as provided by `<security:http><security:form-login /></security:http>` uses a [`SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.RC2/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler.html) to perform the redirection to the login failed url (which defaults to `/spring_security_login?login_error`).
- You can hook your own implementation in by using the `authentication-failure-handler-ref` attribute of your `<form-login>` element.

So, my implementation looks like this:

```
public class UsernameStoringUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler
{
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        request.getSession (true).setAttribute ("SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME", request.getParameter ("j_username"));
        super.onAuthenticationFailure (request, response, exception);
    }
}
```

which is configured thus:

```
    <security:form-login authentication-failure-handler-ref="authenticationFailureHandler" [...] />
    ...
<bean id="authenticationFailureHandler" class="my.package.UsernameStoringUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler" p:defaultFailureUrl="/LoginError" />
```

And then I can access the failed login username using the same approach as described in James Kleeh's answer here, but which no longer worked because of the change to the framework.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do the following to get the username back to the form: In LoginController.groovy:

```
        render view: view, model: [postUrl: postUrl,
                               rememberMeParameter: config.rememberMe.parameter,
                               lastUsername: request.getSession().getAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME")]
```

Comment: `SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME` is deprecated.

Comment: Can you point me to any examples doing what you suggested? I'm struggling on how to do that.

Comment: Just implement `AuthenticationFailureHandler` interface and configure spring-security to use it.

Comment: That still leaves many questions unanswered. An example would be great.

Comment: Have you tried that? What is not working? Anyway it seems like another question to me.