# Get username in controller while login failed

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-security

I'm using Spring Security in my website. While login, if user enters wrong username/password, login fails (which is correct).

What I want to do is to retrieve the value of username in controller which was entered username textbox.

Any idea how I can do that?

Comment: In case, you want to show an error that a user doesn't exist. Don't. from a security point of view never disclose if it was the user name or password that was incorrect. Just that authentication failed.

Comment: I'm displaying *Username/Password incorrect*. My requirement is something else and for that I want to get the value entered in username textbox.

Comment: See this question with answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13035995/1700321.