# i want to retain username when user login page fails in spring security

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

when user given username and password then click on login button. If login fails then redirect to login page but remove username but i want to retain username. i am using spring security version 3.1.4

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return username and password to login form grails spring security](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13035995/return-username-and-password-to-login-form-grails-spring-security)

Answer (score 0):

You can try as below. This worked for me.

```
<input name="email" id="email" type="text" value="${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.authentication.principal}" required email>
```

Hope this helps!!