# Keep username in form input field after unsuccessful login attempt (Java/Spring-security)

Tags: authentication, spring-security, thymeleaf

I've sucessfully set up a [Spring-Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) MVC application using [Spring-Security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/) and form-based authentication. I've implemented a custom login form using [thymeleaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org/), which basically looks like:

```
<form th:action="@{/login}" method="POST">
  <label for="username">Username</label>
  <input type="text" id="username" name="username"/>
  <label for="password">Password</label>
  <input type="password" id="password" name="password"/>
  <button type="submit">Log in</button>
</form>
```

The form is registered as a simple "View Controller" within the `addViewControllers` method of a class extending `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` like:

```
public class LoginController extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login/login");
    registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
  }
}
```

This works so far. There is one thing that bothers me: after a unsuccessful login attempt, the application returns to the login form (which is fine) but both fields are cleared. I'd like to keep the username in the input field (in case just the password was misspelled).

I've tried

```
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" th:value="username"/>
```

but that didn't help.

Is there a way to get the username from the unsuccessful attempt within the thymeleaf template? Do I need to write an explicit controller for that?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/13035995/1700321.

Comment: Thanks @AleksandrM. I saw this question, but since it's nearly three years old I was hoping there would be an easier way by now :) ... So I will go and implement a custom `AuthenticationFailureHandler`.

Answer (score 1):

The crux of this problem is that `SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler`, the default `AuthenticationFailureHandler`, does a redirect- so the request parameters (including the username) will not be available to the login form.

Strangely, for such an obvious thing to want to do, there doesn't seem to be an elegant solution.

If you just need to retain the username then a quick, albeit not very satisfactory, option is to use `SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.authentication.principal` in the template (although note that it will be null on the first visit to the page).

However, you'll find the same problem with the 'remember-me' checkbox, if you use it.

I ended up extending `SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler` and adding the request parameters I wanted to keep (`username` and `remember-me`) to the URL before redirecting.

I'd be very interested to hear if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Could you share your SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler?

Answer (score 0):

As Martin Wilson already pointed out, there is no elegant solution to this problem. However, I got around the problem in my Spring MVC application without using an additional URL parameter. Hopefully that also helps you.

I extended `ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler` to store the username parameter of the login form (`USERNAME_PARAMETER`) in a session parameter (`LAST_USERNAME_KEY`):

```
public class CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler extends ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler {

    // Username field name in the login form
    private final static String USERNAME_PARAMETER = "email";
    // Parameter for retained username
    private static final String LAST_USERNAME_KEY = "LAST_USERNAME";

    public CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler(String defaultFailureUrl) {
        super.setDefaultFailureUrl(defaultFailureUrl);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {

        super.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, exception);
        String lastUserName = request.getParameter(USERNAME_PARAMETER);

        // Store the given username in the session
        try {
            HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
            if (session != null || isAllowSessionCreation()) {
                request.getSession().setAttribute(LAST_USERNAME_KEY, lastUserName);
            }
        } catch (IllegalStateException illegalStateException) {
            LOGGER.debug(Arrays.toString(illegalStateException.getStackTrace()));
        }
    }
}
```

This must be registered as a bean:

```
@Bean
public LogoutSuccessHandler CustomLogoutSuccessHandler() {
    // To redirect to previous url.
    return new CustomLogoutSuccessHandler("/access");
}
```

And it works in my login form as follows. Now the session parameter `LAST_USERNAME` contains the last username:

```
<input class="form-control" name="email" id="email" value="${LAST_USERNAME}" required>
```