# How to get anonymousUser username if login authentication is getting failed in java spring security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am struggling with an issue from last couple of weeks. Please help !

> org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
>   - Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@905571d8:
>   Principal: **anonymousUser**; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated:
>   true; Details:
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@0:
>   RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId:
>   879CE33EC09255373A6D10FAF8B12EE6; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'

I want to know why the username is **anonymousUser** if i enter correct username and incorrect password ?

I want to get the username what i entered in login page. 
Ex- If i enter **admin** in username and incorrect password the username should come admin not anonymousUser.

When i do `auth.getName();` then also i am getting **anonymousUser**.

Please help !!!

**Login.jsp**

```
<form method="post" action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check' />">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-offset-5 col-md-3">
    <div><h2>Login Here</h2> </div>
        <div class="form-login">
        <h4 style="color: red">${message}</h4>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="userName" class="form-control input-sm chat-input" placeholder="Username" required="required" pattern="[0-9]{0,10}" title="Username should not be greater than 10 letters and it should be Alps ID"/>
        </br>                                                   
        <input type="password" name="password" id="userPassword" class="form-control input-sm chat-input" placeholder="Password" required="required" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9!$#%]{8,20}" title="Password should contain A-Z a-z 0-9 ! $ # %"/>
        </br>              
       <!--  <!-- CAPTCHAA -->
        <div class="wrapper">
        <span class="group-btn">                          
            <input type="submit" id="login" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary btn-md"/><!-- <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">login <i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i></a> -->                
        </span>
        </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

**LoginController**

```
@RequestMapping("login")
public ModelAndView getLoginForm(
        String authfailed,
        String logout, String denied,HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, UsernameNotFoundException, IOException {
        String message = "";


    if (authfailed != null) {           
        message = "Invalid username or password, try again !";

        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        String uname = (String) session.getAttribute("username");

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(System.out);          
        //response.sendRedirect("/incidentManagementPortal/PasswordReset");

    } else if (logout != null) {
        request.getSession().invalidate();
        eraseCookie(request,response);
        message = "Logged Out successfully, login again to continue !";

    } else if (denied != null) {
        message = "Access denied for this user !";

    }           
    return new ModelAndView("login", "message", message);
}
```

When authentication is getting failed its going to the above method and if i am useing request.getParameter('username'); i am getting NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just a form post hence you can get it from the request's parameters.

By default, use request.getParameter("j_username"). If you configure custom name for parameter "username" then use request.getParameter("[custom_param_name]").

Ok so you are trying to get the username after Spring security redirects back to the login page for failed authentication. Which Spring Security version are you using? If before 3.1.0, you can get it from session attribute SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME. If not, you can implement AuthenticationFailureHandler to cache it in the session. For details, see: [Return username and password to login form grails spring security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13035995/return-username-and-password-to-login-form-grails-spring-security)

Comment: I have added my Login.jsp and the method from LoginController.java where its going after failed authentication.

Comment: Ok so you are trying to get the username after Spring security redirects back to the login page for failed authentication. Which Spring Security version are you using? If before 3.1.0, you can get it from session attribute `SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME`. If not, you can implement `AuthenticationFailureHandler` to cache it in the session. For details, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13035995/return-username-and-password-to-login-form-grails-spring-security

Answer (score 0):

Using the `AnonymousAuthenticationFilter` you will always end up with an AnonymousAuthenticationToken which by default has principal "anonymousUser"

```
public AnonymousAuthenticationFilter(String key) {
    this(key, "anonymousUser", AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_ANONYMOUS"));
}

protected Authentication createAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request) {
    AnonymousAuthenticationToken auth = new AnonymousAuthenticationToken(key, principal, authorities);
    auth.setDetails(authenticationDetailsSource.buildDetails(request));

    return auth;
}
```

So you could adjust the principal via the constructor but it will always be the same value.
Maybe the AnonymousAuthenticationFilter not not the right tool for your use case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please suggest some method how can i get the value of entered username when authentication is getting failed ?